# res.write() - text on web page all on one line - node.js

Tags: html, node.js

All the text shows up on one line and it includes the <br/ >.

```
res.write("stuff" + "<br/>" + "more stuff");
res.write("words <br/> more words");
res.send();
```

output =

stuff<br/ >more stuffwords <br/ > more words

why are the breaks not working?  Seems to work for everyone suggesting to do so but me lol  I know I'm missing something easy, I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");` before your res.write.

By default content-type is not set to text/html. [express example](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
res.write(`
  stuff
  <br />
  more stuffwords 
  <br /> 
  <p>more words</p>
`);
res.send();
```